# What is $\sup_{z\in \mathbb{D}} |\frac{1}{1-\bar{\lambda}z}|$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{D}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$.  I tried computing $\inf_{z\in \mathbb{D}}|1-\bar{\lambda}z|$ by noting that $|1-\bar{\lambda}z|=|\lambda|\cdot|z-\lambda|\lambda|^{-2}|$, and that the shortest distance from the boundary of the unit circle to the point $\frac{\lambda}{|\lambda|^2}$ is achieved when $z=\frac{\lambda}{|\lambda|}$.

This yielded $\sup_{z\in \mathbb{D}} |\frac{1}{1-\bar{\lambda}z}|=\frac{1}{1-|\lambda|}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Seems correct. You can also note that $|1-{\bar \lambda} z| = |z||{\bar z} - {\bar \lambda}| = |z - \lambda|$ (use that $|z|^2 = z{\bar z} = 1$), so you're looking for the point closest to $\lambda$.